# Angular datatable IE8 issue

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am trying to display Angular datatables (v0.2.1) in my Angular(1.2) app. I have included the necessary jQuery (1.11.1) and es5shim for support. Still, the table just shows a "Loading.." in IE8. On further investigation, I can see the table html is indeed generated but with a display : "none", and the following error creeps up in IE8 Developer tools :

```
TypeError: Object doesn't support this property or method <table style="DISPLAY: none" class="row-border hover ng-isolate-scope" datatable="ng">
```

I am using "Basic Usage - Angular way" as given in the [official docs](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/v0.2.1/#/angularWay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a Polyfill for this to work in IE8.  From the official [Getting Started](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/archives/v0.2.1/#/gettingStarted):

> Angular Datatables is using [Object.create()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/create) to instanciate options and columns.
>
> If you need to support IE8, then you need to add this [Polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-us/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create#Polyfill)

Comment: I was including only es5shim Polyfill, but after reading through its docs got to know that Object.create() is supported by es5sham Polyfill. Now datatable works after adding it! :) Thanks for the help!